# Ploidy of Central cell in embroidery sac

Tags: botany, embryology

In the unfertilized embryo sac in angiosperms, is the central cell considered to be haploid or diploid? though it has two polar nuclei but both of them are haploid, so I don't think it can be considered diploid.
(Actually, I encountered a question that specifically asks the number of haploid cells in an unfertilized embryo sac.)

Please help.